# Docker container only lasted for 5 seconds?

Tags: docker

So there's [tutorial](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Ftoe.bbtower.co.jp%2F20170803%2F2424%2F) about installing Zenko which uses docker.

At step 5, after starting docker container, I checked its exist by using `docker ps` and found out it disappeared after few seconds.
Not sure what happened. Some one please help me!

```
[centos@ip-10-0-7-40 ~]$ docker run -d --rm --name s3server -p 8000:8000 -v /home/centos/.aws/credentials:/root/.aws/credentials -v /home/centos/locationConfig.json:/usr/src/app/locationConfig.json -v /home/centos/config.json:/usr/src/app/config.json -e S3DATA=multiple s3server.custom:1.0
93345a2a3813638bf3bcd984978b7b5ad706b6d15955f0d49269579931d8251d
[centos@ip-10-0-7-40 ~]$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES
93345a2a3813 s3server.custom:1.0 “/usr/src/app/docker…” 2 seconds ago Up 2 seconds 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp s3server
[centos@ip-10-0-7-40 ~]$ docker logs 93345a2a3813
Error response from daemon: No such container: 93345a2a3813
```

Comment: Start it without the `--rm` flag, then you can view the logs.

Comment: Use `docker run -it -p 8000:8000 -v /home/centos/.aws/credentials:/root/.aws/credentials -v /home/centos/locationConfig.json:/usr/src/app/locationConfig.json -v /home/centos/config.json:/usr/src/app/config.json -e S3DATA=multiple s3server.custom:1.0
93345a2a3813638bf3bcd984978b7b5ad706b6d15955f0d49269579931d8251d` and see if you get any errors